# Searching in elasticsearch with proximity(slop) zero and one

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created the following index

```
PUT /proximity_example_1
{
  
    "mappings":{
      "properties":{
        "doc_id": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "test_name":{
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Then indexed a document

```
POST proximity_example_2/_doc
{
  "doc_id": "id1",
  "test_name": "test proximity here"
}
```

Then queried with proximity 0, as follow

```
GET proximity_example_2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "test_name": {
        "query": "proximity test",
        "slop": 0.0 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I didn't get any result, Then I searched with **proximity 1** , and this time also I didn't get any document.
But when I searched with **proximity greater than 1**, I got results.

```
GET proximity_example_2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "test_name": {
        "query": "proximity test",
        "slop": 2.0 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
GET proximity_example_2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "test_name": {
        "query": "proximity test",
        "slop": 3.0 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So does that mean in elasticsearch when we do a search with **proximity** **1** or **0** order of the search term matters?

Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slop with value 0 is as good as normal phrase search(very restrictive and should have search terms in the exact same order in the Elasticsearch), as you increase the slope this restrictiveness gets reduce and you will have more search results, but **beware that increasing to to high number will defeat the purpose of phrase search and you will get irrelevant results.**

You can read [this](https://kb.objectrocket.com/elasticsearch/how-to-use-slop-with-phrase-search-in-elasticsearch-6) and [this](https://marcobonzanini.com/2015/02/09/phrase-match-and-proximity-search-in-elasticsearch/) detailed blog post that explains how it works internally

Comment: @Aimit thank you. So when we are searching with **proximity one and zero, the order of search term matters**, right?

Comment: @sudheesh its not just the order of search terms but the order of search terms in the document which matters most while bringing them in search results

Comment: @sudheesh hope its clear to you now, please upvote and mark it answer if it was helpful\